# Responsive logo on different device sizes on top of slider

Tags: html, css, responsive

I need to make a logo responsive on all devices from large screens to mobile devices. I placed the logo within a row using the following css but my queries doesn't seem to place the logo in the right hand corner when you minimise the screen

I have created media queries but it doesn't seem to scale properly when i resize the web browser.

```
div#row2.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid.vc_row.top-level.standard_section.row2 {

    position: absolute;
    left: 93%;
    z-index: 11 !Important;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Can you also share **HTML**. Thanks

Comment: This is the row i created <div id="row2" data-midnight="dark" data-bg-mobile-hidden="" class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_row top-level standard_section  row2 " style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; "><div class="row-bg-wrap"><div class="inner-wrap"><div class="row-bg    " style=""></div></div><div class="row-bg-overlay"></div></div><div class="col span_12 dark left">

Comment: Not helping out, can you share any code snippet or fiddle link for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is set up using WordPress and the plugin Visual Composer. Is that true?

Comment: Yes Jason it is unfortunately which is really frustrating I'm using a previous child theme and they used visual composer I'm use to creating sites from bootstrap :(